# Visual Studio .dll Reference not found?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference

I had never had this error before, and I didn't move any file, or exclude any reference.

I'm getting this error ([link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/ajax.png)).

In the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll.refresh file, I get a path to the DLL, but it is a path that was located in someone else's computer (who no longer is in charge of this).

It might as well work if I just re-do the reference, but what is weird is that I've used this reference before, and had no problems. I don't know what triggered it..

Does anyone have any clue ?

**--[UPDATE]--**

As expected, I've fixed it, but this question remains unanswered. Besides, the exact same problem with a coworker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the .refresh file and do a Clean and Rebuild.